# ui.draggable isn't getting pushed into an array and displayed with commas using join and push

Tags: php, jquery-ui, join, push

I want the ids of the draggable divs to show up as a comma separated list in the alert button if they were dropped into the droppable_box. Instead there is an alert for each dragged div one after the other instead of as a list.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#draggable1" ).draggable({ grid: [ 20,20 ] });
    $( "#draggable2" ).draggable({ grid: [ 20,20 ] });
     $( "#draggable3" ).draggable({ grid: [ 20,20 ] });

        $( "#droppable_box" ).droppable({

            drop: function( event, ui ) {
            var currentId = $(ui.draggable).attr('id');

            var stuff = [];
            $.each($(ui.draggable), function(i,e) {
                stuff.push(e.id);
            });

            var energy = stuff.join(", ");

            var data = "X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest";

    $('#myId').click(function(){

        $.post (
            "process.php",
            data,
            function(data)
            {
            alert(energy);

            },
            'html'
            );
         });

        }
        });
    });
</script>
```

In the html there are 3 draggable divs

```
<div id="draggable1" class="draggable_meal"></div>
<div id="draggable2" class="draggable_meal"></div>
<div id="draggable3" class="draggable_meal"></div>
```

I changed the jquery a little and published it [here](http://maureenmoore.com/momp_112412/112412.html):

You can look at the view source. Thanks.

In process.php it gives me 1 to 3 arrays depending on how many divs I dragged. I want to push the $_REQUEST object into an array using

```
foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $value) {
            array_push($stack,$value);
          }
print_r($stack);
```

but it gives me 1 to 3 arrays each with the key of zero. How do I get one array out of for example 3 dragged divs?